# .NET MAUI How to implement CallScreeningService?

Tags: android, .net, maui

I want to implement CallScreeningService to know the phone number of the caller while it is ringing. I have followed this documentation [CallScreeningService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/CallScreeningService). The documentation says the app must request the call screening role. But when I request the role in MainActivity.cs, the result is Canceled.

MainActivity.cs

```
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    public static MainActivity ActivityCurrent { get; set; }
    private static int REQUEST_ID = 1;

    public MainActivity()
    {
        ActivityCurrent = this;
    }
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        RoleManager roleManager = (RoleManager)GetSystemService(RoleService);
        Intent intent = 
        roleManager.CreateRequestRoleIntent(RoleManager.RoleCallScreening);
        StartActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ID);
    }
    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent 
    data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ID)
        {
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                // The resultCode is always Canceled
            }
        }

    }
}
```

IncomingCallService.cs (How do I register this Service?)

```
public class IncomingCallService : CallScreeningService
{
    public override void OnScreenCall(Call.Details callDetails)
    {
        var handle = callDetails.GetHandle();
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" 
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_SCREENING_SERVICE" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you miss the attribute for the IncomingCallService? Here is my code:

```
 [Service( Exported = true, Permission = "android.permission.BIND_SCREENING_SERVICE")]
 [IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.telecom.CallScreeningService" })]
 public class IncomingCallService : CallScreeningService
 {
     public override void OnScreenCall(Call.Details callDetails)
     {
         var handle = callDetails.GetHandle();
     }
 }
```

And the request dialog when the app started:

[image]

And the request code I get:

[image]

**Update:**

The debug result:

[image]

**update2:**

[image]

Click the `...` and then click the `Call Device`.

Comment: I did miss it. The result is now "Ok". But when I tried to call my phone, it didn't trigger the `OnScreenCall`

Comment: But it triggered both when I get a call in or I call out. @zvz

Comment: I tested it on the Android 13 emulator. You can check the update part. @zvz

Comment: Will it trigger even if it is still ringing?

Comment: It only triggered before the ring started. @zvz

Comment: I am using a local phone with USB debugging, I also put a breakpoint inside `OnScreenCall` but when I called my phone, it does not trigger the method.

Comment: I tested on the physical xiaomi device again and it will trigger when get a call in not a call out. @zvz

Comment: Did you tested on the other devices? @zvz

Comment: I haven't yet, My phone is Android 11

Comment: You can try to test it on the emulator or some other devices. @zvz

Comment: How can I call the android emulator?

Comment: Please see the update2 part in my answer. @zvz

Comment: Okay thank you.

Comment: I tried it using Android Emulator, and it works. I wonder why it won't work on my local phone?

Comment: I didn't know and it also worked in my loacl xiaomi device. Maybe the phone manufacturer changes something based on the android system. @zvz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255515/discussion-between-zvz-and-liyun-zhang-msft).